# Hi so I'm currently trying to spend an p2pkh utxo, how do create the raw transaction on Bitcoin core, how do I write it? What information do I need?

Tags: p2pkh

https://photos.app.goo.gl/nQMgbBqwyJYvNm516

https://photos.app.goo.gl/3B1KynyQdkB8EA9M9

Need help on to create this p2pkh transaction how is the data written where do write the script pubkey and the script sig

Answer (score 0):

sending from a p2pkh utxo is easy. Check these links out:
https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib/blob/master/examples/spend-p2pkh-txout.py

or,

https://github.com/zeltsi/Mybitcoin

Comment: Please see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer -- link-only answers are subject to link-rot and the goal of this website is to be a repository of enduring useful answers (not just links to answers). You could maybe quote or paraphrase the most relevant parts.